# Issue with the moving of file which is successfully uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please find below the coded section,
You can give your inputs based on the interpretation.

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $content = $_POST['code'];
    if (Storage::exists('file.blade.php'))
    {
        echo "File is already exists..............";
    }
    else
    {
        Storage::disk('local')->put('file.blade.php', $content);
        echo "uploaded successfully..........."; 


        $fileName = "file.blade.php";
        $oldPath = "/storage/app/file.blade.php";
        $destinationPath = "/resources/views";


        File::move($oldPath, $destinationPath);

    }

}
```

I have used the above code trying to move the file. But I got the following error message.

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 176:
>   rename(/storage/app/file.blade.php,/resources/views): The system
>   cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Comment: Is $destinationPath really just supposed to be a directory or a full path to a file? Right now it looks to me like you're trying to move the file to the directory /resources and a file named "views", but I suspect you're trying to keep the filename and move it into the directory "views".

Comment: Also, are you really trying to upload a php file? That sounds like a pretty big security risk!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing like this:

```
$fileName = "file.blade.php";
$oldPath = "/storage/app/file.blade.php";
//$destinationPath = "/resources/views"."$fileName";
$destinationPath = "/resources/views/"."$fileName";
```